# Send post with json from python to node

Tags: python, json, node.js

I am getting some exceptions while trying to make the next code works.

Python 2.7:

```
    jsonDictionaryInner["message"] = message_received
    jsonDictionaryInner["mac"] = repr(myMACInner)
    jsonDictionaryInner["mac"] = jsonDictionaryInner["mac"].replace('\'', '')
    try:
      json_dumped = json.dumps(jsonDictionaryInner)
      headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': myMACInner, 'Content-Length':len(json_dumped)}

      if type_message == "obs":
        requests.post(urlObservation, data=json_dumped, headers=headers)
```

json_dumped looks like this if I print it before posting:

```
{"message": {"measurements": [{"position": 0, "sensor": 11, "value": 26.56}, {"position": 1, "sensor": 12, "value": 90.0}, {"position": 1, "sensor": 13, "value": 23.2}], "id": 34, "observationDate": "2016-03-03 19:39:37"}, "mac": "8b:45:ed:11:77:ab\\n"}
```

I faked the mac but it similar to that one.

In node.js side:

```
app.post('/adddevice', function(req, res) {
  console.log("adddevice");
  addDevice(req.get('authorization'), req.body, function(data){
                                                    res.send(data);
                                            });
});
```

Exception in python side:

```
('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

In node.js side:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at parse (/home/myfolder/myapi/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)
at /home/myfolder/myapi/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (/home/myfolder/myapi/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
at done (/home/myfolder/myapi/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/myfolder/myapi/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I am using express and body-parser in node.js side and json and requests in python's

Answer (score 0):

Seems json payload is being truncated somehow. Could you print what actually Node receiving in payload?

Comment: I can't. Exception is given before "adddevice" is printed. So I can't know what happens. At least, I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/mhedp1kh/ 
check body length also, forgot about that